# creating a top list in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So my brain is having trouble functionning this morning and I can't figure out how to create a Top list.

I have my query like so

```
 $moyennepisode = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM show_moyenne, shows WHERE shows.id = show_moyenne.show_id ORDER BY moyenne DESC LIMIT 100');
 $moyennepisode->execute();

  while  ($show = $moyennepisode->fetch()) { 
somecode }
```

Which is all fine but I simply want to output the position so I tried a for loop but I can't seem to figure out where to place it. I tried an associate array but I failed at that, too.

Can anyone recommend how to do that ? And if there might be a way to do have the position from mmysql instead of php ?

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: To the people downvoting the question, I started doing php four weeks ago, try to remember a time where you didn't know everything about everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$position = 1; 
while ($show = $moyennepisode->fetch()) { 
    Output $position;
    $position++;
    somecode;
}
```

Comment: `for ($position = 1; $show = $moyennepisode->fetch(); $position++ )` is another way of writing this, although possibly not quite as obvious.